# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error of compilation

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a main.cpp file with this line in it :

```
#include "Player.hpp"
```

Here is Player.hpp :

```
class Player {
 private :
  int type; // [0 = humain local, 1 = IA de niveau 1, 2 = IA de niveau 2, 3 = humain en réseau]
  int score;
  int color;
 public :
  Player();
  Player (int type, int color);

  int getType();
  int getScore();
  int getColor();
};
```

And here is Player.cpp :

```
 Player::Player() {
  }

  Player::Player(int type, int color) {
    this->type = type;
    this->color = color;
    this->score = 0;
  }

  int Player::getType() {
    return this->type;
  }
  int Player::getScore() {
    return this->score;
  }
  int Player::getColor() {
    return this->color;
  }
```

If I compile with this line :

```
g++ Main.cpp -o main
```

It shows me the error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Player::getColor()", referenced from: etc...........
```

But if I put the code from Player.cpp below the code from Player.hpp like this :

```
 class Player {
     private :
      int type; // [0 = humain local, 1 = IA de niveau 1, 2 = IA de niveau 2, 3 = humain en réseau]
      int score;
      int color;
     public :
      Player();
      Player (int type, int color);

      int getType();
      int getScore();
      int getColor();
    };

 Player::Player() {
  }

  Player::Player(int type, int color) {
    this->type = type;
    this->color = color;
    this->score = 0;
  }

  int Player::getType() {
    return this->type;
  }
  int Player::getScore() {
    return this->score;
  }
  int Player::getColor() {
    return this->color;
  }
```

it works.

What can I do to fix the problem ? I think it's a problem of compilation.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Each and every .cpp file you have makes up a compile unit. They need to be specified to the compiler explicitly.The *.hpp can be included by .cpp files and don't need to be explicitly specified to your compiler. they however need to be in a specified include directory. You'll see that as your project becomes bigger and more spread over several source files, you'll need to use a build meckanism (like make or even CMake) to automate the calls to the compiler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Main.cpp has a reference to Player.hpp but there is no reference to Player.cpp. Adding the line:

```
#include "Player.cpp"
```

Should solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Your command here,

```
g++ Main.cpp -o main
```

does not compile or link the Player.cpp file, so it correctly says that it can't find the symbols it's talking about in the Player.cpp file.

Add Player.cpp to your build command:

```
g++ Main.cpp Player.cpp -o main
```